# TableAdapter does not save changes to SQL Table

Tags: c#, database, winforms

Good day!

I'm new to C#.

I have DataSet in a Windows Form and I've added a record to DataSet. Then I call TableAdapter.Update(MyTable)   (RowState is in Added mode) . Changes were made and I can see them in my DataGridView bound to SQL MyTable. I can close my Application and start again and I'll see added records.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DimaeSQLDS dsAddToDima = new DimaeSQLDS();

        using (DimaeSQLDSTableAdapters.OrganizationsTableAdapter orgAdapter = new DimaeSQLDSTableAdapters.OrganizationsTableAdapter())
        {
            orgAdapter.Fill(dsAddToDima.Organizations);
            DimaeSQLDS.OrganizationsRow organizationsRow = dsAddToDima.Organizations.NewOrganizationsRow();
            organizationsRow.Address = tbINN.Text;
            organizationsRow.OrgName = tbOrgName.Text;
            organizationsRow.UrFiz = 0;
            dsAddToDima.Organizations.Rows.Add(organizationsRow); //adds row to DataSet      
            this.Validate();
            orgAdapter.Update(dsAddToDima.Organizations);
        }

        this.Close();
    }
```

**Now is my issue**:

I go to Server Explorer -> MyTable (where I added records)-> right click  'Show Table Data' and I see that no records were added to the table. then I start my application again ... and my newly added records were deleted after I've looked into MyTable.

I can't understand this magic! Please help me!

!!!!UPDATE!!!!!

**This is my First Form. Parent Form**

```
namespace DimaeApplication
{
    public partial class fOrganizations: Form
    {

        #region variables
        fAddOrganization addOrganization;
        fContainer container;
        #endregion

        public fOrganizations()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fOrganizations_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dimaeSQLDS.Organizations' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.organizationsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dimaeSQLDS.Organizations);
        }

        public void ReloadBindigs(object sender)
        {

            if (this.tbSearchOrganization.Text == string.Empty)
                this.organizationsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dimaeSQLDS.Organizations);
            else
                try
                {
                    string searchParam = "%" + this.tbSearchOrganization.Text + "%";
                    this.organizationsTableAdapter.FillBy(this.dimaeSQLDS.Organizations, searchParam);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

        }



        private void tsbCreateOrg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (addOrganization == null || addOrganization.IsDisposed)
            {

                addOrganization = new fAddOrganization();
                addOrganization.MdiParent = container ;
                addOrganization.Show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**My Second Form**. Child. I add record here

```
namespace DimaeApplication
{
    public partial class fAddOrganization : Form
    {
        public fAddOrganization()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DimaeSQLDS dsAddToDima = new DimaeSQLDS();

        using (DimaeSQLDSTableAdapters.OrganizationsTableAdapter orgAdapter = new DimaeSQLDSTableAdapters.OrganizationsTableAdapter())
        {
            orgAdapter.Fill(dsAddToDima.Organizations);
            DimaeSQLDS.OrganizationsRow organizationsRow = dsAddToDima.Organizations.NewOrganizationsRow();
            organizationsRow.Address = tbINN.Text;
            organizationsRow.OrgName = tbOrgName.Text;
            organizationsRow.UrFiz = 0;
            dsAddToDima.Organizations.Rows.Add(organizationsRow); //adds row to DataSet      
            this.Validate();
            orgAdapter.Update(dsAddToDima.Organizations);
        }



            this.Close();
        }

        private void fAddOrganization_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            fOrganizations org = new fOrganizations();           
            org.ReloadBindigs(org);
        }      
    }
}
```

Tell me if you need to generate code for each form.

Thank you anyway!!

Comment: Please show us the **connection string** you're using!

Comment: Could it be you have some kind of `TRUNCATE TABLE` thing somewhere you used for testing and forgot to remove?

Comment: Connection String is "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\DimaeSQL.sdf"

Comment: No, I couldn't use Trucate Table anywhere ...

Comment: are you checking the same database table in which you are saving your records..

Comment: if your page code is not very lengthy then may you please show this to us..

Comment: Yes, I'm checking the same table. You see my table Organizations is binded with DataGridView. And when i add new record I refresh my DGV via TableAdapter.Fill (myDataSet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when you are creating project that uses SQL CE Database it creates two copies of your SQL CE Database which  is located on your projects folder on mydocuments and drive c.

Change your connection string with the exact location of your SQL CE Database.

Example :

```
Data Source=C:\\DimaeSQL.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Best Regards

Comment: When i load data from SQL Table I get all my records in DataGridView. Why should master create different connection string to different DB?

Comment: You was right. Some how my TableAdapter loaded data from \Projects\DimaeApplication\DimaeApplication\  . And wrote data to \Projects\DimaeApplication\DimaeApplication\bin\Debug\   . So I changed connetion string in Server Explorer Database to \Projects\DimaeApplication\DimaeApplication\bin\Debug   . Could you explain why did this happen? Why does it different connection string?

Comment: Maybe that's the default thing that visual studio do if you were creating SQL CE database. I don't even know why they did that that why you just need to specify your connection string for now :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a disconnected DataSet. Please try the following:

```
Organizations table = new DimaeSQLDS.Organizations();
using(OrganizationsTableAdapter orgAdapter = new DimaeApplication.DimaeSQLDSTableAdapters.OrganizationsTableAdapter())
{
    orgAdapter.Fill(table);
    DimaeSQLDS.OrganizationsRow organizationsRow = table.NewOrganizationsRow();
    organizationsRow.Address = tbINN.Text;            
    organizationsRow.OrgName = tbOrgName.Text;           
    dsAddToDima.Organizations.Rows.Add(organizationsRow); //adds row to DataSet
    orgAdapter.Update(dsAddToDima.Organizations);
}
```

The Fill(table) is the important part. Even if the table is empty, it starts the change tracking to the database.

Comment: I've done as you said. I've updated my code above... It didn't help. Still the same. I can restart my application many times and new data will appear. but when i open me Table Organizations in Sever Explorer - my new data dissapear (((((